# Complexity Of Determining Tree is balanced?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

```
boolean isBalance(Node root) {
    if (root == null ) 
        return true;
    return Math.abs(getHeight(root.left)-getHeight(root.right)) <=1;
}

int getHeight(Node N) {
    int L = 0;
    int R = 0;
    if (N.L!=null) L = getHeight(N.L);
    if (N.R!=null) R = getHeight(N.R);
    return 1 + Max(L,R);
}
```

I believe that the run time of my algorithm is O(N); But one of my friend told this runs for O(N^2);

My question is whether I am wrong or right since I believe I visit each node once. SO for that its O(N)...

Comment: Note that `isBalanced` will return `true` if the height of the two branches is (near) equal even if the branches themselves are not balanced. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Your `getHeight` method could be simpler (and more correct) if it was handling the `null` case.

```
int getHeight(Node N) {
    if (N==null) return 0
    return 1 + Max(getHeight(N.L),getHeight(N.R));
}
```

Also, I think you should have a read at [this quite similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742844/how-to-determine-if-binary-tree-is-balanced).